# How to get all items from an IMongoCollection where a certain field is present

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongo collection for customers. There is some 280 records in total.

The first 110 records have no BSON object ID, they simply have a customerId field that is of the type int.

After those first 110 the other records have both the customerId field as well as an _id object ID field.

Code that I found in the solution has a premade model for this, that has the Object id defined in it as well.

If I do something like this:

```
List<Customer> customers = _customerCollection.Find(_ => true).ToList();
```

I get an error because there is no BSON object id in the first 110 records. If I change the model and comment out this object id I will get the error when it reaches the ones that do have one.

Is there a way that I can deal with this and make this work? I am in the process of migrating the data and remapping it to other models.

I did not make the mongoDB or the existing code and have never worked with mongoDB, so my knowledge of it is limited.

**Update - example code**

Here is code of the class

```
public class Customer
{
    //[BsonId]
    //[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    //[JsonIgnore]
    //public ObjectId Id;

    //public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public string CustomerDomain { get; set; }

    ...omitted other fields...

}
```

And here is an example document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c05a78ab66f775aefecafd9"),
"CustomerId" : 1000006,
"Warehouse" : "505",
"CustomerName" : "Some name",
"Email" : ""
```

}

Comment: Please add your Customer class and exmaple mongo documents for both cases

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by copying the collection twice. In one copy I removed all BSON object id having documents, in the other collection the other series of documents.

I ran my code twice, changing the model to accommodate the documents I was migrating. (eg once with object ID, once with int ID)